# TensorFlow - Matrix multiplication of matrices cast to float type takes very long time , why?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor

The following matrix multiplication in tensorflow 2.x takes a very long time to execute

```
    a = tf.random.uniform(shape=(9180, 3049))
    b = tf.random.uniform(shape=(3049, 1913))
    a = tf.cast(a ,tf.float16)
    b = tf.cast(b ,tf.float16)
    tf.matmul(a,b)
```

but if I simply use the below method, it's fast

```
    a = tf.random.uniform(shape=(9180, 3049))
    b = tf.random.uniform(shape=(3049, 1913))
    tf.matmul(a,b)
```

Why is it so? and I need to convert the tensor to float for some purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in both of your cases, you are attempting Matrix multiplication of floating values. In the first case you are using float16 and in second case you are using float32.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time
a = tf.random.uniform(shape=(9180, 3049), seed = 10)
b = tf.random.uniform(shape=(3049, 1913), seed = 10)
```

1st run

```
x2 = a
y2 = b
s = time.time()
r2 = tf.matmul(x2,y2)
e = time.time()
print((e-s)*1000)

x1 = tf.cast(a ,tf.float16)
y1 = tf.cast(b ,tf.float16)
s = time.time()
r1 = tf.matmul(x1,y1)
e = time.time()
print((e-s)*1000)
```

Output:

```
184.76319313049316
0.0
```

2nd run after restarting my kernel.

```
x1 = tf.cast(a ,tf.float16)
y1 = tf.cast(b ,tf.float16)
s = time.time()
r1 = tf.matmul(x1,y1)
e = time.time()
print((e-s)*1000)

x2 = a
y2 = b
s = time.time()
r2 = tf.matmul(x2,y2)
e = time.time()
print((e-s)*1000)
```

Output:

```
183.03942680358887
1.0335445404052734
```

Now if I run the same code again without restarting the kernel again even after changing the values of a and b.

```
x1 = tf.cast(a ,tf.float16)
y1 = tf.cast(b ,tf.float16)
s = time.time()
r1 = tf.matmul(x1,y1)
e = time.time()
print((e-s)*1000)

x2 = a
y2 = b
s = time.time()
r2 = tf.matmul(x2,y2)
e = time.time()
print((e-s)*1000)
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.0
```

So essentially it is not a problem of TensorFlow. Tensorflow is executed as a graph. When you run it for the first time it initializes the graph with the mentioned data structure and optimizes it for further calculation. Take a look at the final comment in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15717).

Therefore your second execution for an operation will be faster

Comment: If the solution worked can you please accept and upvote.